# Showing that $\kappa$ is weakly compact in ultrapower.

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, large-cardinals

Suppose $\kappa$ is measurable. In trying to show that there are many weakly compact cardinals below it, I quickly reduced the problem to showing that $\{\alpha < \kappa : \alpha$ is weakly compact $\} \in U$, where $U$ is the $\kappa$-complete, nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\kappa$. Then I just need to show that $\kappa$ is weakly compact in the transitive collapse of the ultrapower.

This seems promising to me, but I can't see how to proceed. How can I prove this?

Comment: Prove that $\kappa$ has the weakly compact property. Note that $\kappa$ is the ultraproduct is represented by the diagonal function.

Comment: Do you know that the transitive collapse of the ultrapower contains all subsets of $\kappa$?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Does it hold only if $U$ is normal?

Comment: @EricWofsey I forget if I've ever seen it proved. I'm not sure how to use the fact anyway.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I'm not sure what property you're talking about. I'm looking for a relatively direct proof from the definition of a weakly compact cardinal.

Comment: Which of the great many definitions of weakly compact are you using?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Satisfying $\kappa \rightarrow (\kappa)^2_2$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to go through the tree property, since $\kappa$ remains strongly inaccessible, this implies weak compactness.

Since the ultrapower is closed under $\kappa$-sequences, if $T$ is a $\kappa$-tree in $M$, it is a $\kappa$-tree in $V$, it has a branch there, and by closure the branch is in $M$.

Comment: Which closure property of the ultrapower are you referring to?

Comment: If $U$ is a normal measure on $\kappa$, and $M$ is $V^\kappa/U$, then $M$ is closed under $\kappa$-sequences.

Comment: Ok, I see that. But then why can't we just take the homogenous set $H\subset \kappa$ of size $\kappa$ and conclude that it's in $M$? It would stay homogenous in $M$ with the same size.

Comment: Sure, that would also work.